# React - Forms - How to deal with child component updates

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, state

I have a form `component` that has a `state` containing an array of `items`.
I am having a hard time trying to update the `state` of the form when one of the `item` inputs gets updated.

At first I was creating a `state` on the items themselves and updating the values using the following code:

```
class ItemRow extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = this.props.item;
    }

    updateItem(event) {
       const target = event.target;
       const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
       const name = target.name;
       this.setState({
          [name]: value
       });
    }

    .....

    render(){
        return (
            <FormControl
                type="text"
                name="name"
                value={this.state.name}
                onChange={this.updateItem}
            />
            <FormControl
                type="text"
                name="price"
                value={this.state.price}
                onChange={this.updateItem}
            />

            .....
        )
    }
}
```

This worked fine for updating the value of the of the inputs, however the `state` was local to the `item` and not reflected or accessible by the `form`

I am trying to figure out how to keep the `state` in the `form` and have the `item` update the state of the `form`

I think this is the right approach but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

At this point I have something similar the following:

```
class Form extends Component{
    this.state = {
        items: [
            { name: 'soup', price: 7, quantity: 1 }
            { name: 'salad', price: 5, quantity: 2 }
        ]
    }

    updateItem(e) {
       // Not sure how to handle updating
    }

    removeItem(item) {
        let items = this.state.items;
        items.splice(items.indexOf(item), 1);
        this.setState({items: items})
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <ItemTable items={this.state.items} updateItem={this.updateItem} removeItem={this.removeItem} />
        )
    }
}
```

ItemTable:

```
class ItemTable extends Component {
    removeItem(item){
        this.props.removeItem(item)
    }

    render(){
       let items = [];
       this.props.items.forEach((item) => {
           items.push(<ItemRow item={item} key={item.id} removeItem={this.removeItem.bind(this,item)} updateItem={this.props.updateItem}/>);
       });
        return(
            {items}
        )
    }
}
```

ItemRow:

```
class ItemRow extends Component {

    removeItem(item){
        this.props.removeItem(item)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <FormControl
                type="text"
                name="name"
                value={this.props.item.name}
                onChange={this.updateItem}
            />

            <FormControl
                type="text"
                name="quantity"
                value={this.props.item.quantity}
                onChange={this.updateItem}
            />

            <FormControl
                type="text"
                name="price"
                value={this.props.item.price}
                onChange={this.updateItem}
            />

            <Button bsStyle="warning" onClick={this.removeItem}><Glyphicon glyph="trash"/></Button>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close to the solution.
If you need to have a state shared between components, you should have it in the most parent component that should be aware of the state (in your case the Form component).

You pass down as props the method "updateItem" from the Form to the ItemTable and then ItemRow (like you're doing)

At this stage, inside the ItemRow you can use the method by calling 'this.props.updateItem' and you can run the function defined in Form, passing some parameters, if you need to.

Comment: Thanks, got it working! Mostly just needed validation that I was heading in the right direction, and a little more logic in place.